# Intercept URL and secure endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, request, endpoint

I have an issue about security of my URI. I want to intercept all my endpoints before responding to any request and I want to add my endpoints' security key that contains combination of date and any security key.

I actually succeeded in combination of security key and date part but I don't want to do that for all my endpoints manually.

I want to do that using interceptor and to add all endpoints automatically. How can I do that? Which technology should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I have explained this on my blog. Have a look. https://www.springframework.in/2019/01/6-introducing-spring-security.html